# Generate a random value in the set {0,1}

Tags: pentaho

Actually the `Generate random value` input allows me to generate an random int, but not in the set I want.

How to generate a random value in the set `{0,1}` with [`Pentaho Data Integration`](http://www.pentaho.fr/explore/pentaho-data-integration/) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a random number in the range of [0..1]  with

http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Generate+Random+Value

and then just round it to an integer of your set {0,1}  via `ROUND()`

http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Calculator

Comment: Did this work for you ?

If so please accept the answer.